# Access formData in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

JS:

```
var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
var formData  = new FormData();

formData.append('file', file)

$.ajaxSetup ({
    processData: false
});

$.post('/addaltproduct',
    {
        file: formData
    },
    function (data) {
        console.log(data);
}).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Controller:

```
if ($request->file('file')) {
    return 'OK';
}
return 'No file';
```

In return I always get 'No file', though if I run `console.log(formData.get('file'))` in JS it shows me the data.

Comment: I don't know exactly what is happening. However, the form to be able to upload file should has the following attributes : `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `formData` directly without an key as the second parameter and set the `contentType` to `false`

```
var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
var formData  = new FormData();

formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('_token', '{{ csrf_token() }}');

$.ajaxSetup ({
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
});

$.post('/addaltproduct', 
    formData,
    function (data) {
        console.log(data);
}).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Then in your controller you could check for file as

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    if($request->file('file')) {
        return 'OK';
    }
}
return 'No File';
```

Comment: working when doing from insomania or postman, giving empty when sending formData from browser